# Backslash added before single quote in magmi ruin my day

Tags: magmi

I know it's such a dump question, but it makes my life difficult. I wonder why in my server, there will be added a backslash before `'` (single quote). So if I input script like `'/home/user/public_html/file.csv'` it will be `\'/home/user/public_html/file.csv\'` when I save the profile. It causes some error because magmi misinterpret the script. I tried to remove it from conf file manually, but then it will be added again everytime I save it. But it only happen in the server with linux, it doesn't happen in my localhost with windows. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your server may have [magic_quotes_gpc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) enabled, which automatically escapes double and single quotes with a backslash.

You can try disabling it by adding the following in your **.htaccess** file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

or using a **php.ini** override:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

You can read more about disabling magic quotes at [PHP: Disable Magic Quotes - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Comment: Thank you, @Axel... I found that the `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc` is off. Now it's set to On but it doesn't give any effect. Is it working right after I change it or it needs sometime to work?

Comment: No, you want to ensure that it's **off**.  Try turning it off, and creating a php file only containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and seeing what state the variable is in.